# how to convert the data of value attribute of request parameter to string content in spring

Tags: spring, string, sap-commerce-cloud, http-request-parameters

i want to get the value of ticket id in string data Type

***@RequestParam(value = "ticketId" , required = false, defaultValue = "false")***

how can i get the value of ticketId in any string data.

Earlier i have tried to do this

```
***@RequestParam(value = "ticketId" String ticketId, required = false, defaultValue = "false")***
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything except the syntax is correct.
Correct syntax:

`@RequestParam(value = "ticketId", required = false) String ticketId`